# mysql filter by date and time separately

Tags: mysql, date, time, filter

I have to perform a query on a MySQL database.
I have a table with records, have a column called "date" (the date type), and a column called "time" (type. Integer is stored by multiplying the time of day by 60. eg 8 am is stored as 480).
Unfortunately, the format of this table can not be modified.
My table stores attentions of doctors on call. The doctors on duty working in two shifts: from 8-20, and 20-8.
I need to know the amount of attention for every doctor.
My query must be filtered by date range and shift.
The problem is that, in the case of doctors working at the turn of 20-8, I have to consider a change of day. (sorry for my bad English).
What I have done is this, this would be an example to date of yesterday, and doctors shift 20-8.

```
SELECT * FROM attentions WHERE (date >= '2015-07-23' and time >=1200) and (date <= '2015-07-24' and time <480)
```

the query does not work at all.

Comment: what is the error message that you get when using mysql_query() or die(mysql_error())?

Comment: I am running directly into the mysql server. I get no error. but returns no records. if I remove the part of "and time <480" I do have results.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing the date field is called: 'a_date' with format 'yyyy-mm-ss' and the time field is a number, the query should be:

```
SELECT * FROM attentions WHERE (date(a_date) >= '2015-07-23' and time >=1200) and (date(a_date) <= '2015-07-24' and time <480)
```

Comment: Why should use the method "date ()" if the value is currently a date?

Comment: because, you want date, not strings compare... But strings compare will work too, because year>month>day..

Comment: You are right, in my example you should not use date function, but in yours you should.
Because the date is a 'strict' word at the mysql system.
You have to change the field name or use date(date) to make the code work.

Comment: @ahmed, or just escape field name as `\`date\``

Comment: I did but not working. I think the problem is the time filter.
actually my real field is not called "date", I put it well to achieve that understanding. because in reality I speak Spanish

Answer (score 0):

Can you check using between?

SELECT * FROM attentions WHERE date between '2015-07-23' and '2015-07-24' and time between 1200 and 480

Comment: I have edited the query using between instead of > or <. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can also use this -

SELECT * FROM ***** where CREATED_DATETIME between '2015-03-12 00:00:00' and '2015-05-11 00:00:00';